# Unable to run nodetool on remote and local server in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax-enterprise, datastax, nodetool

```
nodetool -h <ipaddress> -p 7199 status
Error connecting to remote Jmx agent!
java.rmi.NoSuchObectException: no such object in the table
```

Am getting the above error when I tried to run the nodetool status or any other nodetool command. Cassandra is running fine and nodetool status on other nodes in the cluster shows it is UN state. I tried to add the below entry in cassandra-env.sh file but still I got the same error

JVM_OPTS = "$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname="

Comment: What's your RCP_ADDRESS? can you hit it from localhost?

Comment: RPC_ADDRESS is set 0.0.0.0. I cannot run from localhost as well.

Comment: Does cqlsh work? Please drop your output.log

Comment: Yes, I can login into cqlsh.

Comment: So this tells me that cassandra is up taking requests and that gossip is active. Nodetool relies on JMX. Can you check if the JMX port is being served up by the dse java process?  `sudo netstat -tulpn|grep 7199`

Comment: Yes, it is using the same java process.

Comment: Anything in your system.log

Comment: It is strange that I don't see anything is system.log. "ZERO" errors or warns.

Comment: can you update with the content of your /etc/hosts

Comment: 127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
::1            localhost   localhost.localdomain   localhost6    localhost6.localdomain
x.x.x.x   FQDN     hostname

Answer (score 2):

You have to use your listen_address for nodetool host ip.

```
nodetool -h <listen_address> -p 7199 status
```

or if it is not working, try with **`sudo`**.

Answer (score 0):

In cassandra.yaml file it is written that jmx by default will only work from localhost. To run it from a remote host you need to uncomment and provide values of the parameters written in that file. 
also try

```
cat /var/lob/cassandra/cassandra.log | grep Error
```

see if it gives you any error regarding JMX connectivity